# H5P editor and viewer for Angular

Tags: angular, editor

Anybody working with H5P for angular? I'm trying to develop H5P editor for angular. We can show downloaded H5P contents in angular but I need a way to edit them also. How I start developing this? Any tips will be a big help. [Link to H5P](https://h5p.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the NodeJS implementation of the H5P server: http://github.com/lumieducation/h5p-nodejs-library It includes webcomponents  that might also be usable in Angular.

Comment: Thank you. Start using this. web components in this can be used in angular.